# Calculating user's distance and duration from GPS logs

Tags: sql, postgresql, gps, aggregate-functions, postgis

I am working with a GPS datasets of people's mobility for  [Beijing city](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52367&from=https%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownloads%2Fb16d359d-d164-469e-9fd4-daa38f2b2e13%2Fdefault.aspx).  In my raw GPS table `trajectories` is the sequence of GPS for all users:

```
CREATE TABLE trajectories
(
    user_id integer,
    session_id bigint NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    lat double precision NOT NULL,
    lon double precision NOT NULL,
    alt double precision,
    CONSTRAINT trajectories_pkey PRIMARY KEY (session_id, "timestamp")
);

SELECT * FROM trajectories ORDER BY user_id, timestamp LIMIT 10;
 user_id |   session_id   |       timestamp        |    lat    |    lon     | alt 
---------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+------------+-----
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:04+01 | 39.984702 | 116.318417 | 492
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:10+01 | 39.984683 |  116.31845 | 492
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:15+01 | 39.984686 | 116.318417 | 492
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:20+01 | 39.984688 | 116.318385 | 492
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:25+01 | 39.984655 | 116.318263 | 492
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:30+01 | 39.984611 | 116.318026 | 493
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:35+01 | 39.984608 | 116.317761 | 493
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:40+01 | 39.984563 | 116.317517 | 496
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:45+01 | 39.984539 | 116.317294 | 500
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:50+01 | 39.984606 | 116.317065 | 505
(10 rows)
```

The SELECT query above shows the sequence of GPS points for `user 1`, from the starting point for the current trip (`session_id=20081023025304`). I want to use the raw data in this table to insert calculated trip metrics into a new table I defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE trip_metrics(
  user_id INT,
  session_id BIGINT,
  lat_start DOUBLE PRECISION,
  lat_end DOUBLE PRECISION,
  lon_start DOUBLE PRECISION,
  lon_end DOUBLE PRECISION,
  trip_starttime timestamp,
  trip_endtime timestamp,
  trip_duration DOUBLE PRECISION,
  trip_distance DOUBLE PRECISION,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, session_id, trip_starttime)
  );
```

The point of this `trip_metrics` TABLE is to store results for analysis, so that `lat_start, lon_start` take the values of `lat, lon` of starting position (in the given example: `39.984702, 116.318417`),  `trip_starttimestamp` takes starting time (in this case `2008-10-23 02:53:04+01`) and so the `lat_end, lon_end, trip_endtime` respectively.

And finally using `lat_start/end, lon_start/end` to compute the distance covered by this user in this trip. The final result should be like:

```
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------------+---------------+
| user_id |   session_id   | lat_start |  lat_end  | lon_start  |  lon_end   |     trip_starttime     |      trip_endtime      | trip_duration | trip_distance |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------------+---------------+
|       1 | 20081023025304 | 39.984702 | 39.984606 | 116.318417 | 116.317065 | 2008-10-23 02:53:04+01 | 2008-10-23 02:53:50+01 |               |               |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

With the values of `trip_duration` and `trip_distance` calculated (of course the value of `trip_duration` would be `trip_endtime - trip_starttime`).

I have been stuck in my research for a couple of days thinking about how to do this in `PostgrSQL` database filtering only trips within Beijing city `latitude (39.85 - 40.05)` and `longitude (116.25 - 116.5)` as some trips spanned beyond the city. I created a db-fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=993770cc0ae5164dfd4a2dbe26a0fe52) containing GPS points of 2 trips for this user (10 points each).

I would appreciate any guide to work around this to make a progress in my current research.

**EDIT**

Come across this function to calculate distance using haversine formula. I created this function but I'm not sure how to use it to get `trip_distance` value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION distance(
    lat1 double precision,
    lon1 double precision,
    lat2 double precision,
    lon2 double precision)
  RETURNS double precision AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    R integer = 6371e3; -- Meters
    rad double precision = 0.01745329252;

    φ1 double precision = lat1 * rad;
    φ2 double precision = lat2 * rad;
    Δφ double precision = (lat2-lat1) * rad;
    Δλ double precision = (lon2-lon1) * rad;

    a double precision = sin(Δφ/2) * sin(Δφ/2) + cos(φ1) * cos(φ2) * sin(Δλ/2) * sin(Δλ/2);
    c double precision = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));    
BEGIN                                                     
    RETURN R * c;        
END  
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: Add postgis to your database then read more about geometry/geography functions in it.
You can easily calculate distances (st_distance(geom, geom) or store paths as single records with it.
More you will find here 
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute distances more easily you have to install the [`PostGIS extension`](http://postgis.net/install/), as you already suggest in your tags:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

The function [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) is what you're looking for, e.g (quick&dirty):

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT user_id, session_id, 
    max(timestamp ORDER BY timestamp),
    min(timestamp ORDER BY timestamp) 
  FROM trajectories t
  GROUP BY user_id,session_id  
) 
SELECT 
  s.user_id,s.session_id, 
  lat_start,lon_start, 
  lat_end,lon_end, 
  trip_starttime, 
  trip_endtime,
  age(trip_endtime,trip_starttime),
  ST_Distance(
    ST_MakePoint(lon_start,lat_start)::geography,
    ST_MakePoint(lon_end,lat_end)::geography) AS trip_distance
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    j.user_id, j.session_id, 
    t.timestamp AS trip_starttime,
    lat AS lat_start, lon AS lon_start FROM j
   JOIN trajectories t ON t.timestamp = j.min 
     AND t.session_id = j.session_id AND t.user_id = j.user_id) s,
  (SELECT 
    j.user_id, j.session_id, 
    t.timestamp AS trip_endtime,
    lat AS lat_end,lon AS lon_end FROM j
   JOIN trajectories t ON t.timestamp = j.max 
     AND t.session_id = j.session_id AND t.user_id = j.user_id) e
WHERE s.user_id = e.user_id AND s.session_id = e.session_id;

 user_id |   session_id   | lat_start | lon_start |  lat_end  |  lon_end   |     trip_starttime     |      trip_endtime      |   age    |  trip_distance   
---------+----------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------------------+------------------------+----------+------------------
       1 | 20081023025304 | 39.984702 | 16.318417 | 39.984606 | 116.317065 | 2008-10-23 03:53:04+02 | 2008-10-23 03:53:50+02 | 00:00:46 | 8012597.30391588
```

**On a side note**: Storing longitude and latitude in separated columns is almost always a bad idea. If possible store them into a geometry or geography column. It might seem necessary at first, but PostGIS offers a ton of really [`kickass functions`](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html)!

Further reading:

- [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html)
- [`Date/Time Functions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE)

Comment: To add to my knowledge please, can you explain the sub-query `s` ? I'm wondering how you accessed `t.timestamp, lat AS lat_start, lon AS lon_start FROM j` and to me sub-query `j` returns only four attributes: `user_id, session_id min/max timestamp`.

Comment: the `s` and `e` subqueries only match the exact time of the start and end records. I wrote this join to get the coordinates of both start and end records. My idea with the `j` subquery was to get all max and min values. This query a quick solution and I am sure it is possible to reduce it, but I guess it gives you a good head start

Comment: I get the point. The only issue I noticed is that for users with huge GPS records, `lat_start/end, lon_start/end` take the `max/min lat/lon` values from user's records not be the begin/end coordinates, so the distance computation is not accurate. I noticed this looking at user 10 that covers over 8-hours in 1 trip, but the computed distance was 123.731 meters. When I checked with this user's `lat/lon start/end` values are the `min/max` from trip's record, not `begin/end` coordinates.

Comment: Do the 8 hour records for the user 10 contain the same `session_id`?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm they have the same `session_id`.

Comment: btw, does this query gets the right start/end values for user 10?
`SELECT user_id, session_id, 
    max(timestamp ORDER BY timestamp),
    min(timestamp ORDER BY timestamp) 
  FROM trajectories t
  GROUP BY user_id,session_id`

Comment: Ah, I'm very sorry, I noticed the source of the problem. I examined the source files of this dataset (`geolife by Microsoft`). In this particular, trip I am talking about there are only 908 GPS points, so I suspect it wasn't an 8hrs continues journey, and going through the sequence, I noticed a jump in timing between consecutive points (e.g. `04:34:52,-09:42:25` and `03:05:15-04:08:07` clearly, the user must have stopped at these points, but they recorded it as a single trip.